# Splitting Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm a new coder and am looking to do some calculations on a file to calculate the first quartile (without using special commands like numpy or panda).

I calculated the midpoint of the file and everything was working properly. However when it came time to split up my previously defined dictionary it did not work. This is the code command I tried to use

```
lowerQuartile = myDictionary[myKey:theMidpoint]
```

I get the error: unhashable type 'slice'

Could someone explain to me what this means and any suggestions on how to properly split up my dictionary?

Comment: Dictionaries are (generally) unordered and can't be sliced.

Answer (score 0):

You should use dictionary comprehension since dictionaries aren't slice-able:

```
lowerQuartile = {k:v for i,(k,v) in enumerate(myDictionary.items()) if i < theMidpoint}
```